# PhoneGap APi Call error

Tags: cordova, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2015

using VS 2015 with new Phonegap template from VS2015.

My Ripple is running on http://localhost:4400/index.html?enableripple=cordova-3.0.0-NexusGalaxy 
Trying to call WebApi on IIS on different port on http://localhost:4430

Here is my request url
Request URL:http://localhost:4400/ripple/xhr_proxy?tinyhippos_apikey=ABC&tinyhippos_rurl=http%3A//localhost%3A64260/api/Account/ExternalLogins%3FreturnUrl%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A4400%252Findex.html%26generateState%3Dtrue%26_%3D1449111197287

> Error: {"readyState":4,"responseText":"{\n  \"code\":
>   \"ECONNREFUSED\",\n  \"errno\": \"ECONNREFUSED\",\n  \"syscall\":
>   \"connect\"\n}","responseJSON":{"code":"ECONNREFUSED","errno":"ECONNREFUSED","syscall":"connect"},"status":500,"statusText":"Internal
>   Server Error"} app.js:103 Object {readyState: 4, responseText: "{↵ 
>   "code": "ECONNREFUSED",↵  "errno": "ECONNREFUSED",↵  "syscall":
>   "connect"↵}", responseJSON: Object, status: 500, statusText: "Internal
>   Server Error"}

Have tried adding    to res\xml\config.xml for whitelist plugin

Comment: It's seems to be returning a internal server error. Did you put a break point in your API? Just to be sure, put <access origin="*"/> in your config.xml (the root one not inside platforms.)

Comment: @jpgrassi i do have   <access origin="*" /> on my config.xml, it does not even get to my web api

Comment: Did you solved the problem?